# subfloat alternatives

Tags: subfloats

I'm trying to submit a paper to a journal. I submit the TeX archive which includes the `tex` file + figures in `pdf` format. However, it fails to compile in the queue, whereas it obviously compiles properly on my machine.

Through trial-and-error, I've narrowed down the compile failure to the use of the `subfig` package. If I directly use `\includegraphics` without `\subfloat`, it compiles. However, the spacing for side-by-side figures and figures over multiple lines is much inferior to using subfloat.

My question is, what alternatives do I have to using `\subfloat`, or if I have to space them manually what spacings should I use?

Comment: The `caption` package has a little brother, the `subcaption` package. You may want to give that a go but you need to change some code for that. Have a look at the manual for details

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Or you can use a simple tabular...

Comment: `stackengine` package manual demonstrates how to stack subfigures.

Comment: @MartinH Wanna make your comment into an answer and maybe even mention the approaches by Harish and Steven?